# How to Drag and Drop URL from browser into C/C++ Program

Tags: url, browser, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to develop an app to catalog URLs. I'd like to drag a URL from a browser (e.g. Chrome) into my app to catalog it. I've successfully used the Win API drag and drop functions like DragAcceptFiles and fielded WM_DROPFILES messages but it only works from the File Explorer not from the Chrome URL bar.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Did you have figure out whether this was doable with the WinAPI?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I think the problem is on the *source* end, i.e.. Chrome, and not the *target* end, i.e., my app.